# How to show $(x - a)$ is a factor of a polynomial $p(x)$ if and only if $p(a) = 0$ (without division)

Tags: roots

I am a graduate teaching assistant at a larger state university teaching a college algebra class. Today we begin our decent into polynomials and one of the facts we will soon get to is the connection between roots of a polynomial and linear factors. We do not teach polynomial long division (explicitly avoid it in fact), which is normally how I could convince students that $x - a$ is a factor of a polynomial $p(x)$ if and only if $p(a) = 0$.

My question is how can I convince my students of this fact without appealing to division? Keep in mind that these are largely college freshman who do not necessarily care for explanations. While they would take my word on something and memorize it if I told them it was necessary, I still like to convince them this is indeed mathematical fact and not something that has come out of thin air.

Comment: Without polynomial division? That means *also* without Euclides algorithm...that doesn't look too algebrish to me...and I really have no idea how you're going to teach that stuff and that way. To me, that sounds like trying to teach about extreme points of functions without seeing derivatives...

Comment: Write $\,p(x)\,$ in terms of $\,(x-a)\,$ and prove that the constant term is in fact $\,p(a)\,$.

Comment: Could you maybe assert a form of unique factorization?

Comment: @dxiv that seems promising. I'll probably give that a try.

Comment: @MatthewLeingang I was thinking about that, but seems like it might be a harder pill to swallow that the claim in question.

Comment: "Just like natural numbers can be factored into products of prime numbers, polynomials can be factored..."  Like you said, the standards of proof are lower in this group.

Comment: For any $m\in\mathbb{N}$ we have $(x-a)\mid (x^m-a^m)$. By linearity it follows that $(x-a)\mid (p(x)-p(a))$, hence $p(x)=q(x)(x-a)+p(a)$.

Comment: Let $Q(x)=P(x+a)$. Since $Q(0)=0$, the constant term of $Q$ is zero so $Q(x)=xR(x)$. Thus, if we replace $x$ by $x-a$ and let $T(x)=R(x-a)$, we obtain $P(x)=(x-a)T(x)$.

Comment: Given the students don't require a proof, I think this is not a strong need pedagogically.

Comment: Based on my experience (20 years at the university and community college level), most of these answers are impractical at the college algebra level. You're better off spending 10 minutes on the idea of division (you don't need to actually do any - even demonstrating with division of two integers) and using the traditional explanation. They won't understand these more complex explanations.

Answer (score 6):

This answer presumes that the students know polynomial multiplication. In particular, 
$$(x-a)(x^{n-1}+ax^{n-2}+\cdots+a^{n-1})=x^{n}-a^{n}.$$
Since 
$$p(x) = c_{n}x^{n}+c_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\cdots+c_0=(x-a)q(x),$$
and
$$p(a) = c_{n}a^{n}+c_{n-1}a^{n-1}+\cdots+c_0,$$
we have
$$p(x)-p(a) = c_n (x^{n}-a^{n})+c_{n-1}(x^{n-1}-a^{n-1})+\cdots+c_1(x-a)=(x-a)r(x).$$
Consequently,
$$p(a) = p(x)-(x-a)r(x)=(x-a)(q(x)-r(x)).$$
The L.H.S. is a constant, whereas the R.H.S. contains $x$. So $q(x)-r(x)=0$, and $p(a)=0$.

Comment: Said *structurally* it's true when $p(x)$ is a monomial $x^n$ so by innate *linearity* it's true for all polynomials, being linear combinations of monomials.

Answer (score 6):

One way to avoid (explicit) division is to make a change of change variables $\, X = x-a\,$ which reduces it to the following simpler special case    $$ X\mid P(X) \iff \color{#c00}{P(0)} = 0$$
Explicitly we have $$\qquad\qquad\begin{eqnarray}  
& x-a\,&\mid\,\ p(x) \\[.21em]
\iff\ & X\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\! &\mid\ \ p(X+a)\\[.2em]
\iff\ & &\  \color{#c00}{\bigl[p(X+a)\bigr]_{X=0}} = 0\quad\text{by above special case}\\[.2em]
\iff\  & &\ \ p(a) = 0
\end{eqnarray}$$

**Remark** $  $ This approach implicitly uses the fact that the above shift map is a *ring automorphism* - something that is implicitly known since high school but not usually proven *rigorously* until a course in abstract algebra. See [this MSE answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/94729) for further discussion on such pedagogical subtleties.

Comment: Reminds me of [this](http://mathforum.org/kb/message.jspa?messageID=330971), which I recently cited [here](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/13639/interesting-but-very-easy-epsilon-delta-problems/13655#13655).

Comment: @Dave Indeed, simplifications by way of shifts (automorphisms) are helpful not only in algebra, but also in analysis, e.g. for proving *in*equalities (as in those explicit $\epsilon$-$\delta$ proofs of limits).

Answer (score 4):

Let $\,p(x) = c_n x^n + c_{n-1} x^{n-1} + \ldots +c_1 x + c_0\,$, and expand it in powers of $\,(x-a)\,$:

$$
\begin{align}
p(x) &= c_n\big((x-a)+a\big)^n+c_{n-1}\big((x-a)+a\big)^{n-1}+\ldots+c_1\big((x-a)+a\big)+c_0 \\
 &= c_n\left((x-a)^n+\binom{n}{1}(x-a)^{n-1}\cdot a+ \ldots+\binom{n}{n-1}(x-a)\cdot a^{n-1} + \color{red}{a^n}\right) \\
 &\quad + c_{n-1}\left((x-a)^{n-1}+\binom{n-1}{1}(x-a)^{n-2}\cdot a+ \ldots+\binom{n-1}{n-2}(x-a)\cdot a^{n-2} + \color{red}{a^{n-1}}\right) \\
 &\quad \cdots \\[5px]
 &\quad + c_1\big((x-a) + \color{red}{a^1}\big) \\
 &\quad + c_0 \cdot \color{red}{a^0} \\[5px]
 &= (x-a)q(x) + \color{red}{c_n a^n}+\color{red}{c_{n-1}a^{n-1}}+ \ldots + \color{red}{c_1 a} + \color{red}{c_0} \\[5px]
 &= (x-a) q(x) + p(a)
\end{align}
$$

It then follows that $\,(x-a) \mid p(x) \iff p(a) = 0\,$.

Answer (score 1):

If you could first convince them of the fundamental theorem of algebra (and if they know of complex numbers) then one writes $p(x)=c\prod_i(x-\alpha_i)$, substituting $a$ will have to convince them from that point that there is $i$ such that $\alpha_i=a$.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if there's a great way of explaining it without division (I feel like any good explanation will strongly hint at division) but maybe you could "disguise" the division by talking about repeated subtraction.

You can subtract any multiple of $x-17$ from a polynomial. That includes multiples like $10x^{82}(x-17)=10x^{83}-170x^{82}$.

In fact, given *any* polynomial of degree $\ge1$, say its leading term is $ax^n$, you can subtract $ax^{n-1}(x-17)$ and get a polynomial of strictly smaller degree. And as long as you keep getting polynomials of degree $\ge1$, this process can be repeated. But it can't continue forever. So eventually we get a polynomial of degree $<1$, i.e., a constant. Call that constant $c$.

So, if the original polynomial was $p(x)$, we get $p(x)-(\mbox{some multiple of ($x-17$)})=c$. Then evaluate at $x=17$.

Now that I look at what I've typed, it's not very different from the standard argument. But it's possible that phrasing it in terms of repeated subtraction, rather than polynomial division, may be helpful to some of your students.

Comment: This is *precisely* the [standard inductive proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/918255/242) of the Polynomial Division Algorithm, i.e. decrease the degree of the dividend by subtracting a multiple of the divisor (scaled so they have equal lead terms), then proceed inductively on the remaining smaller degree dividend. Interpreted constructively this induction yields the recursion for the standard Polynomial Division Algorithm. See [also here.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/215792/242) This [extends easily](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/116037/242) to non-monic divisors.

Answer (score 0):

To *prove* the assertion, you need polynomial division. But to *demonstrate* with enough examples that they develop an intuition (you're probably going to help them discover it on their own, right?) all they need is the ability to *factor* polynomials. I'd think you could start simple with something like this:

$f(x) = (x+1)(x-5)$

What is $f(-1)$?

So the class calculates $f(-1)$ and finds it is zero. (Will you need to discuss what a root means in terms of a polynomial?) Do this three or four times with different functions, asking for a single root. Then ask for all roots, not just one. Ask the class what pattern they are seeing and if they think that pattern holds for all polynomials. See if they can guess the other root of $f(x)$, above.

This may not get the class to be able to construct a proof that goes both ways, but it should give them an understanding of how to apply the proof -- which is really the aim (assuming the class is not composed exclusively of math majors).

Comment: That's the trivial direction, i.e. for some polynomial $q(x):\ p(x) = (x-a)q(x)\,\Longrightarrow\, p(a) = 0.\,$ Proving the reverse direction is where the difficulty lies, and that has little to do with *factoring* polynomials. Also one doesn't "need" the Polynomial Division Algorithm to prove it, e.g. see my answer.

Answer (score -3):

We have by division algorithm that $$f(x)=(x-a)Q(x)+R$$where $R$ is the real residue of division therefore $$f(x)=R$$which means that $$R=0\leftarrow\rightarrow f(a)=0$$

Comment: You must have missed the important point that the OP wants to avoid *completely* polynomial division...

Comment: Indeed. This is exactly what I would normally do, but my students do not know polynomial division (or at least it is not covered in the class and is therefore a technique that I can rely on using).

Comment: Well! This is the most essential definition and intuition about division. How would you replace it with something better?

Comment: @MostafaAyaz It is beyond my pay grade. Like I said, this is indeed how I would do it.